# Sharing Symfony2 validation rules with backbone.js or javascript in general?

Tags: javascript, validation, symfony, backbone.js

Would it be possible to expose **Symfony2** validation rules (for a given Entity)? I can't find anything like this. I'm trying to do client-side validation (using **backbone.js**) with a DRY approach. Something like a bundle or any tip would help.

[Here is](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Validator.html) the component validator. One possibility would be:

**Define server-side validation** rules using Symfony2 standard way. Example (YAML, taken from their website):

```
# src/Acme/BlogBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml
Acme\BlogBundle\Entity\Author:
    properties:
        name:
            - NotBlank: ~
```

Make `/author/rules` return a **JSON object which maps fields from the entity to a "compiled" regular expression**. I'm not so sure about this but I think that internally  Symfony2 compiles `validation.yml` rules into regular expressions.

Assuming an author entity made of `name` field with `NotBlank` (note i'm not a master in regex, this is a copy and paste from another question):

```
{ 'name' : '^\s*\S' }
```

Finally retrieve that JSON object and do **client-side validation with backbone.js** system. **Possibly do caching**. For example (warning! pseudo-code-like code inside `validate()`):

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        window.MyApp = window.MyApp || { Models : {}, Views : {}, Router : {} };

        window.MyApp.Models.Author = Backbone.Models.extend({
            initialize : function() { _.bindAll(this, 'validate') },
            validator : $.get('/author/rules');
            validate: function(attrs) {

               // Loop each property of this model
               _.each(attrs, function(field, value) {

                   // Get the regex from the validatior
                   var rule  = this.validator[field];
                   var regex = new RegExp(rule);

                   if(!regex.test(value)) return "Model not valid.";

               }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Am I asking for the moon?

Comment: Maybe you are on to something! I guess there is no way to do it right now, but there might be a way to turn this into a bundle! I would suggest not to use ajax in this case, simply because loading validation rules every time is a huge overhead. But what about exporting the rules from the yml to a javascript file which defines the different regex so you can use them with backbone.js (or whatever javascript code you would like)?

Comment: @Boo thanks for your comment. Unfortunately i'm not so good in Symfony2 to make a bundle right know. And i think that exporting rules from yaml to javascript (and then write javascript rules - again) is overkill - there should be some way of getting "compiled" rules directly from Symfony2.

Comment: Well, if you are going to use ajax, you can also just validate the object within symfony and return the result of the validation via ajax return message. So if you want to validate name of Author, you send an request to /author/validate containing the username, the controller validates it using symfony validation and returns if validation was successfull or not. Depending on this you show error messages.

Comment: Have you seen this bundle https://github.com/Abhoryo/APYJsFormValidationBundle, I've been considering using to address the similar goal as yourself, however right now it only supports Annotation based constraints, which has put me of.

Comment: I think about writing the bundle for Symfony2 in order to make work with Backbone.js in Symfony2 easier. What would you like to have?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this bundle. I've used it with varied success in the past.

https://github.com/formapro/JsFormValidatorBundle

It exports all of the Symfony validation rules and dumps then in to a JS data structure. Then there are various helpers to allow you to enforce these validations. Also remember to disable HTML5 form validation with `<form novalidate="novalidate">` etc

<s>I think it may be limited to Symfony <= 2.6 but I've got it working up to Symfony 2.7.7. The maintainers are currently working on Symfony 3.0 support I think.</s>

This bundle is still in active development:

- Version 1.2 supports Symfony <= 2.6
- 1.3 for Symfony 2.7 - 2.8
- 1.4 for 3.0
- 1.5 for 3.1
- 1.6 for 4 (although this is currently a pre-release)

Answer (score 0):

This bundle may suit your needs [APYJsFormValidationBundle](https://github.com/Abhoryo/APYJsFormValidationBundle)

However it is currently limited to assert defined constraints, applied to entities.

Support for php, yml and xml defined constraints are on the todo list.

Comment: APYJsFormValidationBundle is no longer maintained. But JsFormValidatorBundle mentioned in the answer by @Benr77 has support for Symfony4